# RegEx - Only one valid email

Tags: regex, email

I know it's my fault and it is not complicated but I cannot find the answer by myself so I beg you to help me build this RegEx.

I'm trying to avoid users to enter more than one email address by line, so I'd like to limit the "@" occurrences to only 1 and also check there are not commas (,)....

Here's a simplified version of the RegEx I'm already using to check the input....

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

How could I introduced a section to check there are not (@,) on the last part ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just to add an `^` and one `$`

```
^\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Beaner's solution also did the trick...
Now I'm still looking if I can avoid people to enter more than one subdomain, like foo@mymail.com.uk.it.com..... but even if cannot... now is good enough for me.....

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using a regex, you could `split` the string at the @, and count how many elements the output array has.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am currently using. A quick test limited it to a single valid email for me.

```
@"^(?!.*\.\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\w\._%&!'*=?^+-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$"
```

Comment: Right offhand I can see that you aren't allowing a + before the @, so you aren't following the standard.

Comment: Writing a standards compliant regex for emails is... hard.

Comment: tloach was correct. I edited my regex accordingly. Hopefully I will make it a little better every time I visit it. Code review is one of the things that makes stackoverflow valuable.